# xpages: custom addOnLoad event on my xpage

Tags: xpages, xpages-ssjs

The scenario:

Clicking on a link, I'm accessing an xpage, let say: `start.xsp`.

I've added the following script to this .xsp:

```
<xp:scriptBlock id="scriptBlock1">
        <xp:this.value><![CDATA[
        XSP.addOnLoad(function(){
            XSP.openDialog("#{id:dialogSearch}")
        });
    ]]></xp:this.value>
    </xp:scriptBlock>
```

So, every time this .xsp is loaded, a dialog is showing up. The problem is the current `start.xsp` is being refreshed/loaded many times, considering the fact that the xpage have numerous fields/controls on it. It is uncomfortable every time this start.xsp is loaded / refreshed the dialog to show up.

Is it possible to show the dialog after the `start.xsp` is loaded but ONLY when the above link was clicked? I do want firstly to go to that xpage and after this to show the respective dialog.

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set a session scope variable in your link

```xml
<xp:link
    escape="true"
    text="Link"
    id="link1">
    <xp:eventHandler
        event="onclick"
        submit="true"
        refreshMode="complete">
        <xp:this.action><![CDATA[#{javascript:
            sessionScope.showDialogSearch = "yes"; 
            context.redirectToPage("start.xsp")
        }]]></xp:this.action>
    </xp:eventHandler>
</xp:link>
```

Add a rendered attribute to your start.xsp's xp:scriptBlock

```xml
    <xp:this.rendered><![CDATA[#{javascript:
        var show = sessionScope.showDialogSearch;
        sessionScope.remove("showDialogSearch"); 
        return show
    }]]></xp:this.rendered>
```

This way dialog is only be shown if start.xsp was executed from your link and only once because it gets deleted at first use in rendered attribute.

Comment: Thanks @KnutHerrmann. Actually, it is a link, not a button ( my mistake ). is it possible into a link also, right?

Comment: After I close the dialog, and let say I'm on the same start.xsp which contains a view panel: I open some doc. listed by the viewpanel, and then click a Cancel button ( which goes to $Previous page ), the dialog is showing up again. Sorry, if I'm missing something from your explanations.

Comment: Great! Offtopic question: How can I quote my code inside the question, being like XML xpages code? Thanks

Comment: Just add `<!-- language: lang-xml -->` in front of your code to get syntax highlighting. You can find a detailed description here http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/184109/223607.